# FeathersJS Mongoose: Updating matched sub-document not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, feathersjs

I want to update a value of a sub-document where a message has a specific id and an user id is in a recipient array. I want to update a value of the matched object with the specified user id.

When I run the following query on the MongoDB CLI, everything works and the value is updated:

```
db.getCollection('messages').update({
  _id : ObjectId("57d7edb8c497a75a6a7fde60"),
  "recipients.userId" : "5789127ae2bcc79326462dbc"
},{
  $set : {"recipients.$.read": true}
});
```

But when I run the following query via JS in my FeathersJS application:

```
messageService.update({
  _id : '57d7edb8c497a75a6a7fde60',
  "recipients.userId" : "5789127ae2bcc79326462dbc"
},{
  $set: {"recipients.$.read": true}
}).then(function(e) {
  console.log(e)
}).catch(function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

I get the error:

> GeneralError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: recipients.$.read

What am I doing wrong?

**And is there a better way of updating many messages at once?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For updating one or multiple records by a query you need to call the [service method](https://docs.feathersjs.com/services/readme.html#service-methods) by setting `id` to `null` and putting the query into `params.query`:

```
messageService.update(null, {
  $set: {"recipients.$.read": true}
}, {
  query: {
    _id : '57d7edb8c497a75a6a7fde60',
    "recipients.userId" : "5789127ae2bcc79326462dbc"
  }
}).then(function(e) {
  console.log(e)
}).catch(function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Makes sense for me, but when I run this code I get an "Error: [object Object]" response

Comment: Maybe https://docs.feathersjs.com/debugging/readme.html can help to get a better error message (might be a bug that it is not converting the error properly).